# Triangle preserving ratio in proportion to canvas size in Processing

Tags: processing

In Processing:

I have to build a house  - square and triangle that keeps its proportion when I change the background.
this is my code:

```
void setup () {
 size(400,400);
 background(#9DD5FF);

 }
 void draw (){
{  fill(#FFA600);
stroke (#FFA600);
rect (width/2,height/2,100,100);
triangle (250,100,200,200,300,200);
}}
```

I know how to keep the rectangle - but no idea about the triangle. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code you posted doesn't change the rectangle's size, so it's not really changing the proportion at all, just the location. You probably want something like this:

```
rect(width/2, height/2, width/4, height/4);
```

Anyway, the best thing I can tell you to do is get out some graph paper and a pencil, and draw a bunch of examples. If your window is 1000x1000, what should the positions of each point be? What if it's 100x100, or 500x500?

Keep drawing examples until you notice a pattern. You want all of your parameters to be based on the `width` and `height` variables.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a basic tutorial on this, available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/using-variables).

If you still can't figure it out, then post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not your whole project, just the triangle bit) in a new question post and we'll go from there. Good luck.